# The fix points of the Möbius transformations are the eigenspace of a certain matrix.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing

Let $M=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a & b  \\
c & d  \\
\end{array} \right) \in GL_{2}(\mathbb{C})$ and we recall that the  Möbius transformation attached to $M$ is the map:

$z \to \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$

then **I have to show that the fix points correspond to the eigenspace of** $M$.

My attempt is:

We first divide by $z$, then we have

$\frac{a+b/z}{c+d/z}$

Consider that $\infty$ is a fixpoint therefore $z =\infty \Rightarrow \frac{a+b/z}{c+d/z} \to \frac{a}{c}$ thus $c=0$, another fix point turns out from the equation:

$\frac{a}{d}z + \frac{b}{d}=z \Rightarrow z = \frac{b}{d-a}$

**But then how can I could justificate the part of the fix points correspond to the eigenspace of** $M$, **Can someone help me to prove this please, I think it should be easy, but I really do not know how to attack it. Thanks for the help in advance.**

**then what can you tell me about my question ?**

**your answers will be very welcome :)**

***THE BOUNTY HAS NOT FINISH, YOUR ANSWERS ARE STILL WELCOME :)***

Comment: I am here in the discusion :)

Comment: I am in the discussion.

Comment: then what can you tell me about my question ?

Comment: your answers will be very welcome :)

Comment: your answers will be very welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(z) = \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$. The key observation is

$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}a & b \\ c & d\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c}z \\ 1\end{array}\right) = 
\left(\begin{array}{c}az + b \\ cz + d\end{array}\right) = 
(cz+d)\left(\begin{array}{c}\frac{az + b}{cz + d} \\ 1\end{array}\right) = 
(cz+d)\left(\begin{array}{c}f(z) \\ 1\end{array}\right)$$

I'll let you take it from here. From this you can relate eigenvectors and fixed points. Remember to consider the special case when there's an eigenvector of the form $\left(\begin{array}{c}1 \\ 0\end{array}\right)$, which corresponds to a fixed point at $z = \infty$ (as you already partially worked out).

Comment: thanks for the answer :), but the way I can related are by computing the eigen vectors of which matrix?

Comment: I think I need more help :), I am so sorry but I am at second year of my carreer in math, and I am not vey acquanted with the Riemman sphere, and the observation i s good but I think I need more help please, thanks

Comment: You don't need to compute the eigenvectors, just show a correspondence between fixed points and eigenvectors (i.e. given one, show how to make the other). Look at the formula I have. What does it take for $\left(\begin{array}{c} z \\ 1 \end{array}\right)$ to be an eigenvector of the matrix $M$?

Comment: You can ignore the comment I had about the Riemann sphere. I just meant that $z = \infty$ could be a fixed point too.

Comment: well Mx=0 with x not 0

Comment: ok, but that is for What does it take for (z,1) to be an eigenvector of the matrix M?

Comment: Look at the big displayed equation I have above (just the first and last terms of it). If $f(z) = z$ then that implies $\left(\begin{array}{c} z \\ 1 \end{array}\right)$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $cz + d$.

Comment: but you talk of a correspondence , and that is the confusing part to me :), the above thing of eigenvalues and eigenvectors how can I aplied them to the correspondence?

Comment: Maybe the term was confusing, I meant: If I hand you a fixed point $f(z) = z$ you can hand me an eigenvector of $M$, namely you'd hand me $\left(\begin{array}{c} z \\ 1 \end{array}\right)$. Now if I hand you an eigenvector of $M$, can you hand me back a fixed point? (Hint: scale your eigenvector so its second coordinate is $1$.) Then we can say fixed points and eigenvectors are _in 1-to-1 correspondence_.

Comment: Well I I think there is a lot of work isn't? Jajajaja is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Well this is because the teacher said that it was easy :)

Comment: This is really the cleanest way to go about it. Sit down and think about it for a little while. It will probably seem easy in retrospect. The other way I guess would be to write down the explicit equations you need to solve for a fixed point and then again the explicit equations to solve for an eigenvector and then relate those.

Comment: Ok let me try your idea and if I get stuck can I let you know?

Comment: Sure, I'll probably check back periodically.

Comment: Thank you a lot and that will be excellent because I do not know if tomorrow or may on Monday because now here is late and appreciate that :)

Comment: Hello @aes my attempt and my question is here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1035693/working-with-the-mobius-transformatios-and-linear-algebra, can you check it out please :) thanks in advance