# Verifying the convergence of a series.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

I need to prove that the series $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}3^{-n}$$ converges and to find the limit.

My attempt:

We can express our series as:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3^{n}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\bigg(\frac{1}{3}\bigg)^{n}$$

And this is a geometric series of the form $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n}$$ and we know that it converges whenever $|x|<1$, that is our case, and moreover we know that:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n}=\frac{1}{1-x} \Rightarrow  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\big(\frac{1}{3}\big)^{n} = \frac{1}{1-1/3}=\frac{1}{2/3}=\frac{3}{2}$$

*Can you tell me if I am right, or what can I improve with my proof?*

**Can you help me with this question:**

[The fix points of the Möbius transformations are the eigenspace of a certain matrix.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1031879/the-fix-points-of-the-m%C3%B6bius-transformations-are-the-eigenspace-of-a-certain-mat)

[image]

Comment: You're right, it's correct proof.

Comment: thank you :) Can you help me with this please is because none answers a this question :) thanks in advance http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1031879/the-fix-points-of-the-m%C3%B6bius-transformations-are-the-eigenspace-of-a-certain-mat

Answer (score 3):

You are of course right. The issue is context, what are you expected to do? If it has already  been proved in your course that all geometric series with "$|r|$" less than $1$ converge, and if a formula has been derived for the sum, then what you did is fine. But it is a peculiarly simple question to ask if one has that machinery in hand.

So I am inclined to think that you are expected to prove the convergence from the definition. In that case, you would be expected to compute $s_M=\sum_0^M \frac{1}{3^n}$, and show that the sequence $(s_M)$ converges.

Comment: Well We are using Gaughan Analysis book, where it is stated in page 176 at Example 6.4 that the geometric series converges to that limit and that cindition :)

Comment: Does the problem follow that example? Is a proof given in the example?

Comment: well what we can do is that I will post a photograph of that example and you tell me right :)

Comment: OK, or maybe someone has that book and can answer. On what page is the problem?

Comment: is at page 207 :)

Comment: there is it :) what can you tell me :)?

Comment: No proof is given. In a book with analysis in the title, I would expect that quoting an unproved comment would not be sufficient.

Comment: then can you present one proof of this please :)

Comment: We need to prove, perhaps by induction, that $\sum_{n=0}^M 3^{-n}=\frac{1-3^{-M+1}}{1-\frac{1}{3}}$. Then the limit as $M\to\infty$ is not difficult.

Comment: Is the answer of @NidiaGonzalinajec enough? or we need to do this?

Comment: Ratio Test is an odd thing to use, since ultimately the Ratio Test depends on the convergence of geometric series with $|r|\lt 1$. Whether your solution is enough is course-context dependent. It would be enough in the typical first year calculus course.

Comment: well and your conclusion what would be ?

Comment: You may be able to gauge expectations based on your previous experience in the course. If you are uncertain, ask the instructor or the person in chaarge of grading.

Comment: ok let me ask :), and well I think everything will be fine, but just in case, I can check the proof of this in other books isnt?, or can you post one?

Answer (score 1):

Are you allowed to use the Ratio test in your solution? If so, $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}|\frac{1}{3^{n+1}} \cdot \frac{3^n}{1}|=\frac{1}{3}<1$ so $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3^{n}}$ converges absolutely.

Comment: yes I am allowed to use the the ratio test but I do not undestand your idea :) thanks

Comment: ok I got it therefore it converges :) and no more confusion with this proof isnt?, just the part of the sum, how can we have it?