# Is my proof right of this result?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

Suppose that:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$

converges absolutely and $\{b_n\}$ is bounded.Prove that

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}b_n$

converges absolutely.

My attempt:

Let $M$ be the upper bound of $\{|b_n|\}$, then we have the following

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_{n}b_{n}| \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_{n}M|=M\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_{n}|$

And given that:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$ converges absolutely  by the comparison test we are done

Am I right or what can I improve in my proof? thanks in advance

**Can you help me with this question please :)**

[The fix points of the Möbius transformations are the eigenspace of a certain matrix.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1031879/the-fix-points-of-the-m%C3%B6bius-transformations-are-the-eigenspace-of-a-certain-mat)

Comment: It is complete and correct, just remove the part on $\sum|c_n \alpha|$.

Comment: thanks then everything is fine :), and can you help me with this please :) http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1031879/the-fix-points-of-the-m%C3%B6bius-transformations-are-the-eigenspace-of-a-certain-mat

Comment: You want $M$ to be an upper bound on $|b_n|$, not just on $b_n$.

Comment: ok then let me edited, right :)

Comment: there is it :) now is right isnt?