# Proving the limit comparison test

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

I have the next attempt:

Because $0<L< \infty$,  we can find two positive and finite numbers, $m$ and $M$, such that $m<L<M$.  Now, because $L = lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}$ we know that for large enough $n$ the quotient  must be close to $L$ and so there must be a positive integer $N$ such that if $n>N$ we also have, $m<\frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}<M $, multiplying by $b_{n}$ gives, $m{b_{n}}<{a_{n}}<M{b_{n}}$ provided $n>N$ .

Now, if $\sum b_{n}$ diverges then so does $\sum mb_{n}$ and so since $mb_{n}$ for all sufficiently large n by the Comparison Test $\sum a_{n}$ also diverges.

Likewise, if $\sum b_{n}$ converges then so does $\sum Mb_{n}$ and since $a_n<Mb_n$ for all sufficiently large n by the Comparison Test $\sum a_{n}$ also converges.

Am I right or what can I improve?, **And with this how can I attack the conclusion when** $L=0$ **(this is in my proof where is the contradiction when $L=0$)?,thanks a lot**

Comment: Looks good. If the limit is $0$  you will only get results in one direction. If the series $\sum b_n$ converges, then so does $\sum a_n$. Same proof. But if $\sum b_n$ diverges, we cannot conclude anything about $\sum a_n$.

Comment: ok then my proof is right :) isnt, but, i do not undestand the other part of the comment :)

Comment: For limit $0$, unfixable.

Comment: ok then my proof is right :) isnt, but, i do not undestand the other part of the comment :)

Comment: Let $b_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$. Then $\sum \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ diverges. Let $a_n=1/n$. Limit of ratio is $0$, but $\sum 1/n$ diverges. Let $a_n=1/n^2$. Limit of ratio is $0$, but $\sum a_n$ converges.

Comment: can you restate your comment please so I can undestand it better :)

Comment: then It is enough to put that counterexample to tell what happens at L=0?

Comment: Yes. If the limit is not $0$ then the test works in both directions. If the limit is $0$, then the test works in one direction but not the other, and the two examples are enough to show that.

Comment: ok and in my proof everything is fine isnt?, can you help me with this please http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1031879/the-fix-points-of-the-m%C3%B6bius-transformations-are-the-eigenspace-of-a-certain-mat

Comment: Your proof for $L\e 0$ was of good quality.

Comment: I dont understand :)?

Comment: Do I have to say at the begining that wolg I am considering 0<L?

Comment: I assumed that the $a_n$, $b_n$ are positive,so the issue of $L\lt 0$ does not arise. All of this is about absolute convergence so if (implausibly) some terms are negative, we work with their absolute values.

Comment: ok then now everything is fine isnt?, and another thing can you help me with http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1031879/the-fix-points-of-the-m%C3%B6bius-transformations-are-the-eigenspace-of-a-certain-mat

Comment: Not my area of full comfort! In course-related problems, I prefer to stay with courses I have taught, since then I know precisely what it can be expected the student knows.

Comment: Ok well I appreciate your interest, and with this then everything good and nothing to change isnt?  :),

Comment: Your solution, as I said earlier, is good. Note that you are assuming everything is positive.

Comment: thanks a lot @AndréNicolas for everything :)I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: You are welcome. You wrote up your solution in a clear and mature way.