# Working with the Mobius transformatios and linear algebra.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing

Let $M=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a & b  \\
c & d  \\
\end{array} \right) \in GL_{2}(\mathbb{C})$ and we recall that the  Möbius transformation attached to $M$ is the map:

$z \to \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$

then **I have to show that the fix points correspond to the eigenspace of** $M$.

My attempt is:

We must show that there is a one-one correspondence between the eigenvectors of $M$ and the fix points, so we have the following:

Let $f(z) = \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$. The we observe that:

$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}a & b \\ c & d\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c}z \\ 1\end{array}\right) = 
\left(\begin{array}{c}az + b \\ cz + d\end{array}\right) = 
(cz+d)\left(\begin{array}{c}\frac{az + b}{cz + d} \\ 1\end{array}\right) = 
(cz+d)\left(\begin{array}{c}f(z) \\ 1\end{array}\right)$$

**Is the above the big displayed equation?**

let $z$ such that $f(z)=z$, then we have that:

$$(cz+d)\left(\begin{array}{c}f(z) \\ 1\end{array}\right)=(cz+d)\left(\begin{array}{c}z \\ 1\end{array}\right)$$

therefore if $z$ is a fix point we asociate it the eigenvector $(z,1)$ with eigenvalue $(cz+d)$.

Now we  suppose that $\vec z = \left(\begin{array}{c}z_{1} \\ z_{2}\end{array}\right)$ is a eigenvector, then we scale it, so  $\vec z = \left(\begin{array}{c} \frac{z_{1}}{z_{2}} \\ 1\end{array}\right)$

then we need to find:

$(cz+d) \left(\begin{array}{c}f(\frac{z_{1}}{z_{2}}) \\ 1\end{array}\right)= (cz+d)\left(\begin{array}{c}\frac{a\frac{z_{1}}{z_{2}}+b}{c\frac{z_{1}}{z_{2}}+d} \\ 1\end{array}\right)=(cz+d)\left(\begin{array}{c}\frac{\frac{az_{1}+bz_{2}}{z_{2}}}{\frac{cz_{1}+dz_{2}}{z_{2}}} \\ 1\end{array}\right)=(cz+d)\left(\begin{array}{c}\frac{az_{1}+bz_{2}}{cz_{1}+dz_{2}} \\ 1\end{array}\right) = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a & b  \\
c & d  \\
\end{array} \right) \left(\begin{array}{c} \frac{z_{1}}{z_{2}} \\ 1\end{array}\right)=\lambda \left(\begin{array}{c} \frac{z_{1}}{z_{2}} \\ 1\end{array}\right)$

MY question is, first of all Am I in the good way or what do I have to fix?,and the other one is what can be conclude from here **(this is think that my eigenvector is not rigth, how can I fix that part,I dont know how to find the other side of the correspondence.)**  Can you help me to complete this problem please, thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't compute the eigenvalues! Suppose something is an eigenvalue, and then scale it so its second coordinate is 1. Then it should fit into the big displayed equation with almost no more work (i.e. use the big equation, but in the reverse of how you were using it).

Comment: thanks for the help again :), but which is meaning of scale ?

Comment: and I compute the eigenvectors not values :)

Comment: well I dont undestand your comment, which is meaning of scale,and I compute the eigenvectors not values  :) thanks,

Comment: I have edit my post :), Is that what you told me in your comment?

Comment: Yes, you scaled it correctly. Now this is also an eigenvector. So go back up to the big displayed equation and you'll be able to conclude $z = z_1/z_2$ is a fixed point.

Comment: ok the big displayed equation is the one that I bold isnt?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: ok another question, we can conclude that z1/z2 is a fix point evaluating f( z1/z2) isnt?

Comment: Yes, that's equivalent, but do that if it makes you more comfortable. Write out $f(z_1/z_2)$ in terms of $a, b, c, d$ and also write out the equation that (z_1, z_2) is an eigenvector.

Comment: ok let me do it and I posted for verification right ?

Comment: Ready, am I right?

Comment: Now use that it's an eigenvector.

Comment: mmm I actually did it when I write the part of the multiplication of matrices isnt?

Comment: You haven't shown it's a fixed point yet. Use $\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a & b  \\
c & d  \\
\end{array} \right) \left(\begin{array}{c} \frac{z_{1}}{z_{2}} \\ 1\end{array}\right) = \lambda \left(\begin{array}{c} \frac{z_{1}}{z_{2}} \\ 1\end{array}\right)$. (Also, there's a minor problem with the way you've written it, since some terms are vectors and some are not.)

Comment: well that was the missing step, and how can I fix the that?

Comment: Replace the $f(z_1/z_2)$ at the left end of that equation with $(c z_1/z_2 + d) \left(\begin{array}{c} f(z_1/z_2) \\ 1 \end{array}\right)$.

Comment: can you edited please, I dont undestand, I am sorry for that :)

Comment: what can you say now?, am I done or what else do I need to do? thanks :)

Comment: I mean: Do the left half of your calculation with $\left(\begin{array}{c} stuff \\ 1\end{array}\right)$ (wherever you have a scalar, use this instead). Then, to get it to be equal to the right half of your calculation, you'll need to multiply everything by $cz_1/z_2 + d$ (you'll see when you do it, or alternatively, it's because of the big equation at the top).

Comment: mm I not undestandind :( I am sorry

Comment: I edited it. As long as you understand why that equation is true, and why it then implies that $f(z_1/z_2)$ is a fixed point, you're done. (z = z_1/z_2)

Comment: ok then with your edit We are done?